# limit $(x^2+y^2)e^{-(x+y)}$ when $(x,y)$ approach infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Limit $(x^2+y^2)e^{-(x+y)}$ when $(x,y)$ approach infinity
I don't know how to solve it. 
I've tried the following :

Set $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ and I've used $r$

In result, I got infinity.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with the above solution. I tried to vote it up but I am a newbie ;). However it does not explain why you are wrong and often substituting bounds makes things more difficult conceptually.

1)The reason your answer is wrong is firstly, from the conditions you have given us, $x$ is not related to $y$. Under your subsititutions, $y^{2} = r^{2}-x^{2}$. Also it doesn't help you moveforward as the exponent is not in $x^{2}$ and $y^{2}$ but $x$ and $y$.

2) Your function can be written as $x^{2}e^{-x} \times y^{2}e^-{y}$. Both of these terms go to 0 as $x$ and $y$ go to infinity. The exponential dominates the polynomial. To see this intuitively you can go into $\log$ space, $\log(x^{2}) = 2 \log(x)$ and $\log(e^{-x}) = -x$, now you may be familiar with the $\log$ function, it tails off to grow less than linear quite quickly.

Comment: but I did not understand what this gives us. Does the limit exist or tends to zero?

Comment: I don't understand this part  "The exponential dominates the polynomial"

Comment: The limit is $0$. The exponential dominates the polynomial. Think of $Ax-Bx^{2}$ it doesn't matter how big A is and how small B is, there comes a point where $x^{2}$ dominates $x$, and exponential of x, dominates any polynomial of $x$. As the exponential can be written as an infinite polynomial in $x$.

Comment: I am ashamed of being stupid but I don’t understand how we get 0 when the exponential dominates the polynomial. And in general, if we go into the space of logarithms, then we have a logarithm from x ^ 2 is and increasing function and logarithm from from an exponential is decreasing

Comment: if it’s not difficult, can it  be somehow illustrate this?

Comment: @ZELIBOBA because you can write $e^{x}$ as an infinite polynomial in $x$ using the taylor expansion around $x=0$. Think of it likes this, imagine you have the function $1/x^{2} \times e^{x}$ now writing the taylor expansion as $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}((x^{i}/i!)$  we have  $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}((x-2)^{i}/i!)$  we can see that for large x, it still tends to infinity. So the exponential dominates the polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $x,y > 0, x^2+y^2 \le(x+y)^2 \implies 0 < f(x,y) \le \dfrac{u^2}{e^{u}}$ by twice L’hospital rule with $u = x+y$ . Thus the limit is $0$ by Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: Squeeze Theorem doesn't work cuz we should have g(x) <= f(x) <= h(x) Instead of this we have g(x) <  f(x) <= h(x)

Comment: @ZELIBOBA The $\leq$ vs $<$ you mention doesn't affect the validity of the squeeze theorem.

Comment: @b00nheT can you explain   why?